# CakePHP 3 DISTINCT has no effect on generated query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, distinct, query-builder

CakePHP 3.5.13

```
$query = $Substances->find()->select(['id']);
debug($query->sql());
```

Produces:

```
'SELECT Substances.id AS `Substances__id` FROM substances Substances'
```

Trying to do the MySQL equivalent of `DISTINCT()` by changing the query to:

```
$query = $Substances->find()->select(['id'])->distinct(['id']);
```

Results in exactly the same query string as without `->distinct()`:

```
'SELECT Substances.id AS `Substances__id` FROM substances Substances'
```

Why is this? According to the [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data), that's how you write a `DISTINCT()` query using Cake's ORM.

Comment: `$Substances->find()->select(['id'])->distinct();` should work

Comment: It does. But look at the linked documentation - it gives an example of `->distinct(['country']);`.

Comment: The example is incorrect/misleading. When passing a value to `Query::distinct()` you are saying that you want only those columns to be used for duplicate row elimination, but that isn't supported by all dialects, hence it might be compiled differently accordingly, for MySQL it will be turned into a `GROUP BY` clause (ie, you're maybe not showing the complete query).